# Ручной маппинг в веб интерфейсе (java)

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

Подскажите лучшие инструменты для написание веб интерфейса, задача - маппинг 2х java классов.

Пользователь выбирает 2 класса, рефлексией на страничке отображаются все атрибуты. Их нужно соединить, например стрелочками.

Думаю в сторону `Vaadin/GWT`. Если кто решал схожую задачу, подскажите лучший алгоритм действий. спс. (only java frmwrk)

Comment: не очень понимаю вашшу идею и какие проблемы будет решать ПО.  пользователь сам соединяет стрелками поля одного класса с другой ?

Comment: ну да, у него есть 2 класса, он говорит значение каких полей в какие маппятся. ну то есть.

class Person{
int age;
String name;
}
class Individ{
int level;
String shortName;
String fullName;
}
вот он хочет, чтобы из person в individ в левел клалось поле age, а в name - fullname;

Comment: ну тогда испольщуй Vaadin. вопрос очень общий и сложно ответить на него